# Código malicioso em Online Judge

Tags: php

Estou criando um online judge, como o Spoj, UVa e outros. Já tenho a minha parte Web, que foi feita em PHP, onde é possivel submeter os códigos e tenho um servidor em Python que recebe os mesmos, executa o código e já me retorna o resultado do programa (AC, WA, TLE, RTE).
Porém o que eu preciso agora é tratar os códigos que chegam, para não ser possivel por exemplo executar comando do OS. Não queria ter que percorrer o código inteiro e ficar verificando se existe alguma função que eu não permito, pois dessa forma daria muito trabalho, pois a cada nova linguagem que eu adicionasse no meu OJ, teria que descobrir quais são as funções maliciosas.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Se possível explique melhor o que pretende fazer, dê mais detalhes, pois a pergunta atualmente está difícil compreender aonde você quer chegar.

Comment: Preciso que quando os códigos cheguem no meu servidor em Python eles sejam tratados de alguma forma, para evitar código maliciosos.
Como executar comandos do OS, mexer em arquivos, abrir Sockets e Threads. Tudo isso tem que ser evitado.

Answer (score 2):

Prever todas as situações que você vai enfrentar é muito dificil, o mais prático é criar o código de forma a só permitir certas situações e tudo que estiver de fora, não pode ser executado.

Trabalhar com uma black list é praticamente inviável, sugiro você trabalhar com uma white list e/ou um validador de expressões para validar os tipos de expressoes que podem ser executados.

A lista de palavras reservadas de qualquer linguagem pode ser achada facilmente na internet.

Além disso, você também pode restringir alguns tipos de execuções com base na configuração de seu ambiente (nao rodar codigo como adminstrador, não dar permissão de escrita em pastas, etc).

Outra preocupação seria XSS (cross side scripting) e Transversal Path (que permitiria ler seus arquivos de configuração, por exemplo), você pode encontrar um referencia a estes tipos de ataques aqui: https://www.owasp.org/

Veja bem, não é uma tarefa fácil projetar software para executar ações especificas, projetar software para rodar software é muito mais difícil, se tivesse de escolher um caminho, iria pela regra do menor privilégio, que basicamente diz para projetar o código de forma que ele rode com o menor privilégio possivel.

Um bom livro genérico sobre segurança:

http://www.saraiva.com.br/como-quebrar-codigos-a-arte-de-explorar-e-proteger-software-182830.html